# Find word plus additional characters in Excel cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with text in a cell - I'd like to extract the specific text and an additional 5 characters alongside it.

For example:

Cell A1 contains the text - 'Here is the cell for widget 1A1A and its content'. I'd like to find any cell that contains the word 'widget' and extract that and the following 5 characters (including space). So the result would be 'Widget 1A1A'.

Comment: Do you want to use a VBA code?

Comment: Ideally an Excel formula.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite straightforward. Use the SEARCH command to find the word "widget" (FIND is the same but case-sensitive):

```
=SEARCH("widget",A1)
```

This gives you the character number in the cell where the match is found [if no match is found it returns "#N/A".

Then match this with the MID function to pull in the text "Widget" + the following 5 characters, as follows:

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH("widget",A1), LEN("widget") + 5)
```